# conexão via socket server android, cliente c#, servidor dentro de outra rede

Tags: c#, android, socket, ip

Já consegui fazer a comunicação C# -> Android sem problemas, mas quando o Android se conecta a uma rede local, não sei como realizar essa conexão via ip, ja que ele adquire o IP local. Consigo obter o IP do modem ao qual ele está conectado e seu IP local, mas não sei como criar essa nova conexão.

Codigo da conexão em C#

```
public static byte[] Send(string ip, byte[] toSendBytes, int port)
{
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        IPEndPoint serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
        clientSocket.Connect(serverAddress);

        //enviando
        byte[] toSendLenBytes = new byte[4];
        int total = toSendBytes.Length;
        toSendLenBytes[3] = (byte)((total >> 24) & 0xFF);
        toSendLenBytes[2] = (byte)((total >> 16) & 0xFF);
        toSendLenBytes[1] = (byte)((total >> 8) & 0xFF);
        toSendLenBytes[0] = (byte)(total & 0xFF);
        clientSocket.Send(toSendLenBytes);
        clientSocket.Send(toSendBytes);


        // recebendo resposta
        byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
        clientSocket.Receive(rcvLenBytes);
        int rcvLen = System.BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);
        byte[] rcvBytes = new byte[rcvLen];
        int pos = 0;
        clientSocket.Receive(rcvBytes);
        clientSocket.Close();
        return rcvBytes;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Erro\n" + e.Message + "\n" + e);
    }
    return null;
}
```